# How to configure Microsoft ConversationBot with custom storaged based on Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, microsoft-teams

Using the Microsoft Teams Toolkit I created a simple notification bot in c#. The generated bot uses the default LocalFileStorage. The docs indicate "you should use your own storage for production". I've created a simple store based on EF and it works great for the *first* event from Teams. However, subsequent events will throw "System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed context instance." when the store tries to interact with the EF _context instance. So, I've got something not right in the DI configuration.

```
builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
{
    // my EF backed store
    services.AddScoped<IConversationReferenceStore, ConversationReferenceStore>(); 

    // *
    // This code generated from TeamsFX SDK app generator for Notification Bot.

    // Create the Bot Framework Authentication to be used with the Bot Adapter.
    services.AddSingleton<BotFrameworkAuthentication, ConfigurationBotFrameworkAuthentication>();

    // Create the Cloud Adapter with error handling enabled.
    // Note: some classes expect a BotAdapter and some expect a BotFrameworkHttpAdapter, so
    // register the same adapter instance for all types.
    services.AddSingleton<CloudAdapter, BotAdapterWithErrorHandler>();
    services.AddSingleton<IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter>(sp => sp.GetService<CloudAdapter>());
    services.AddSingleton<BotAdapter>(sp => sp.GetService<CloudAdapter>());

    // Create the Conversation with notification feature enabled. 
    services.AddScoped(sp =>
    {
        // Get ref to my store to pass to options
        var store = sp.GetService<IConversationReferenceStore>();
        var options = new ConversationOptions()
        {
            Adapter = sp.GetService<CloudAdapter>(),
            Notification = new NotificationOptions
            {
                BotAppId = botId,
                Store = store
            }
        };

        return new ConversationBot(options);
    });
```

Bit of my store

```
public class ConversationReferenceStore : IConversationReferenceStore
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _context;
    private readonly ILogger<ConversationReferenceStore> _log;

    public ConversationReferenceStore(MyDbContext context, ILogger<ConversationReferenceStore> log)
    {
        _context = context;
        _log = log;
    }

    async Task<bool> IConversationReferenceStore.Add(string key, ConversationReference reference, ConversationReferenceStoreAddOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Second request blows with disposed exception
        var conversation = await _context.Conversations.FindAsync(new object[] { key }, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        ...
```

Further discovery: Though I've registered the ConversationBot as Scoped, the NotificationMiddleware is a singleton and is holding on to a reference to the IConversationReferenceStore.

Answer (score 0):

The root issue, I found, is that the internal class Microsoft.TeamsFx.Conversation.NotificiationMiddleware is holding on to the instance to the configured store. An instance of this NotificationMiddlware is attached to the Adapter. So, I needed to change the adapter's registration as scoped as well.

```
// Create the Cloud Adapter with error handling enabled.
// Note: some classes expect a BotAdapter and some expect a BotFrameworkHttpAdapter, so
// register the same adapter instance for all types.
services.AddScoped<CloudAdapter, BotAdapterWithErrorHandler>();
services.AddScoped<IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter>(sp => sp.GetService<CloudAdapter>());
services.AddScoped<BotAdapter>(sp => sp.GetService<CloudAdapter>());
```